# MediaWiki pagination

Tags: mediawiki, pagination

Is there are way to paginate a set of MediaWiki pages so that there is automatically a "next" and "previous" link at the top or bottom?

This may be for a set of pages in a particular category, for example, and would allow the user to click through each page in order.

Answer (score 1):

I think here is a good example of pagination in MediaWiki: https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Demo:Listwidget_paginated_list
Maybe you can figure out, how it works.